# Combine Result From Two Tables and Distinct By Date/Hour

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get count of results found. Individually those two queries works fine, no trouble there.

But when I try to get result combined (I've used `UNION`). I get the result right but result from the second table appends to the result set.

### For Example

**The result from table one:**

When I use simple queries.

```
array(28) {
    [0]=> object(stdClass)#139 (7) { 
        ["date"]=> string(10) "2014-06-16"
        ["total"]=> string(1) "2"
        ["emails"]=> string(1) "0"
        ["calls"]=> string(1) "2"
        ["qualified"]=> string(1) "2"
    }
}
```

**The result from table Two:**

```
array(28) {
    [0]=> object(stdClass)#139 (7) { 
        ["date"]=> string(10) "2014-06-16"
        ["no_answer"]=> string(1) "1"
        ["voicemail"]=> string(1) "1" 
    }
}
```

*Shown only one object per result for simplification*. **Notice** Notice those two result are from same date but they are added twice in the result set on the combined query.

**The combined result (with current function):**

```
array(28) {
    [0]=> object(stdClass)#139 (7) { 
        ["date"]=> string(10) "2014-06-16"
        ["total"]=> string(1) "2"
        ["emails"]=> string(1) "0"
        ["calls"]=> string(1) "2"
        ["qualified"]=> string(1) "2"
        ["no_answer"]=> string(1) "0"
        ["voicemail"]=> string(1) "0" 
    },

    [1]=> object(stdClass)#139 (7) { 
        ["date"]=> string(10) "2014-06-16"
        ["total"]=> string(1) "0"
        ["emails"]=> string(1) "0"
        ["calls"]=> string(1) "0"
        ["qualified"]=> string(1) "0"
        ["no_answer"]=> string(1) "1"
        ["voicemail"]=> string(1) "1" 
}
```

**Desired Result I want is:**

In the result I want Each result to represent a single date (no duplicate date).

```
    [0]=> object(stdClass)#139 (7) { 
        ["date"]=> string(10) "2014-06-16"
        ["total"]=> string(1) "2"
        ["emails"]=> string(1) "0"
        ["calls"]=> string(1) "2"
        ["qualified"]=> string(1) "2"
        ["no_answer"]=> string(1) "1"
        ["voicemail"]=> string(1) "1"
```

### The Full Function

```
//Note: function is simplified

    function get_lead_numbers_by_distinct_days($num_days, $user_id){
        global $wpdb;
        $leads_table = 'leads';
        $calls_table = 'calls';


            $sql1 = "SELECT Date(date) date,
                    COUNT(type) total,
                    SUM(type='email') emails,
                    SUM(type='call') calls,
                    SUM(qualified=1) qualified,
                    SUM('') no_answer,
                    SUM('') voicemail

                    FROM $leads_table WHERE user_id = $user_id
                    AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL $num_days DAY) <= date

                    GROUP BY DATE(date)";


            $sql2 = "SELECT Date(date) date,
                    SUM('') total,
                    SUM('') emails,
                    SUM('') calls,
                    SUM('') qualified,
                    SUM(status='no-answer') no_answer,
                    SUM(status='machine') voicemail

                    FROM $calls_table WHERE user_id = $user_id
                    AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL $num_days DAY) <= date

                    GROUP BY DATE(date)";

            $sql = "$sql1

            UNION

            $sql2
            ";

            $data = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

        return $data;
    }
```

Empty `SUM()` is used to match column numbers. Otherwise MySQL shows error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally had to drop the `UNION` and use `JOIN` instead. Here is the final query.

```
                SELECT $leads_table.date date,
                COUNT($leads_table.type) total,
                SUM($leads_table.type='email') emails,
                SUM($leads_table.type='call') calls,
                SUM($leads_table.qualified=1) qualified,
                SUM($calls_table.status='no-answer') no_answer,
                SUM($calls_table.status='machine') voicemail

                FROM $leads_table
                LEFT JOIN $calls_table

                ON ($leads_table.object_id = $calls_table.ID)

                WHERE user_id = $user_id
                AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL $num_days DAY) <= date

                GROUP BY $group_by($leads_table.date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Union should have been worked . Check the datatype of the values in both the table .They have to be identical if you wanna union them.

Comment: Union returns the results okey, but the result sets are not combined (rather appended) which results two result entry for a single date.

Comment: If the date is not there means you can do this by select sum(value) from( ($sql1 ) union ($sql2)) . Since you have date you can manually add the results by php, checking the dates.

Answer (score 0):

First of all - u don't need to make sum, if u know the result. Just replace:

```
SUM('') no_answer,
SUM('') voicemail
```

with

```
0 no_answer,
0 voicemail
```

secondary - you perform a group by in 2 separate queries, and in order to get the full result u should perform it together.

therefore your combined query should look like this:

```
SELECT  Date(date) date,
        COUNT(type) total,
        SUM(type='email') emails,
        SUM(type='call') calls,
        SUM(qualified=1) qualified,
        SUM(status='no-answer') no_answer,
        SUM(status='machine') voicemail 
FROM (
    SELECT date, type, qualified, 0 status  
    FROM leads_table 
    WHERE user_id = $user_id
      AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL $num_days DAY) <= date

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT date, 0, 0 , status 
    FROM calls_table
    WHERE user_id = $user_id
      AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL $num_days DAY) <= date
) a
GROUP BY Date(date);
```

Comment: And this is not so good in high scale performance because it perform filesort, so if u need it to be performance optimised - just create a table where u will save the calculated data for future reference, and calculate it only once for each day.